# Why is my html e-mail blank in GMail? (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email

I'm trying to send a HTML e-mail using codeigniter but when I check my inbox using GMail the message is blank. Why is it doing this?

**I have checked similar questions but none seem to provide an answer that worked.**

This is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Email extends CI_Controller {



    public function index()
    {


        $message = $this->load->view("email/default_view",True);

        $email_config = Array(
            'protocol'  => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => '465',
            'smtp_user' => '****************',
            'smtp_pass' => '****************',
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'starttls'  => true,
            'newline'   => "\r\n"
        );

        $this->load->library("email",$email_config);

        $this->email->from('*******', '*********');
        $this->email->to('********'); 

        $this->email->subject("Re: Contact");
        $this->email->message($message);    

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();

    }

}
```

And my view:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Some text</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I get no errors from "print_debugger()" and the message appears as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `TRUE` as the third parameter to the view:

```
$message = $this->load->view("email/default_view", null , true);
```